# Which is the most secure and fast way of transferring large amount of data (SQL Server backup files) to Azure Blob or Azure VM hosting SQL

Tags: sql-server, migration, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am considering options apart from Azure Import Export.

The data is more than 2Tb. but divided into multiple files. I would have 8-10 files ranging from 30Gb to 500Gb And we can use certificates for any web service that can be utilized for this transfer.

AzCopy is usually recommended for transfer of data upto 100GB or less.

Azure Data Factory, Data management Gateway by creating a pipeline and gateway and transferring data.

Please do suggest if there is any other way to do this transfer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my experience, Azcopy will provide you the best performance and is recommended even when data size is greater than 20 TB. Read [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4045257/troubleshooter-for-azure-file-blob-and-storage-account-transfer-proble) following KB article for more information.

One thing you should determine is which datacenter provides the lower BLOB storage latency based on your location. Use [this](http://azurespeedtest.azurewebsites.net/) URL for that purpose. The lower the values you get on that URL, the better.